# Hadoop Credentials using Password File

Tags: hadoop

I was going through the doncumentaion of Hadoop Credentials as provided in
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CredentialProviderAPI.html

But while using the 3rd option to Provide password for keystone using password file, I am getting a failure everytime. An excerpt of the command used is provided below. Can anyone tell me what is the error and how to rectify this.

```
hadoop credential -Dhadoop.security.credstore.java-keystore-provider.password-file=/home/dir/test.txt create mssql2.password -value 'SomePassword' -provider localjceks://file/home/dir/aws3.jceks
```

The Error is provided below:

```
java.io.IOException: Password file does not exist
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.locatePassword(ProviderUtils.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.locateKeystore(AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.java:86)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.LocalJavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(LocalJavaKeyStoreProvider.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.LocalJavaKeyStoreProvider.<init>(LocalJavaKeyStoreProvider.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.LocalJavaKeyStoreProvider$Factory.createProvider(LocalJavaKeyStoreProvider.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialProviderFactory.getProviders(CredentialProviderFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell$Command.getCredentialProvider(CredentialShell.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell$CreateCommand.validate(CredentialShell.java:345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell.run(CredentialShell.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.alias.CredentialShell.main(CredentialShell.java:460)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, this property expect the file name not the file path and then Hadoop api will search for this name on the Hadoop Classpath. Since this file contains clear text so another way is to just
`export HADOOP_CREDSTORE_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}`